# QEMU adding new arguments to qemu binary

Tags: c, linux-kernel, emulation, qemu

I am new to qemu development. I am trying to modify qemu to emulate some features of SGX processor on x86 machines using QEMU emulator. Here is what I want to do.

I want to add the following to qemu. I want to start a qemu process with a new argument EECREATE. This when given to qemu-i386 binary should create an encrypted space in memory with few new data structures inside. Like for example,

qemu-system-i386 -hda ubuntu.img -eecreate -m 2G

This command should boot an ubuntu.img and create a encrypted space (need not be big) of memory for the image (In this case create an encrypted space within 2G that is assigned to the ubuntu-img. Basically, the encrypted space should be within a address space of the image.)

Can anyone please let me know the process involved as what needs to be followed to get it working? What files I need to modify? A brief explaination of how the flow of code will be? 
I am not able to get any documentation on web and am stuck as where and how to begin.Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Way too broad.  If the Qemu project declares not having documentation beyond the code itself--among those invested--how should a StackOverflow Q&A suddenly produce the missing documentation?  But as the Qemu codebase can be searched via the GitHub mirror, did you consider typing in "argv" or "argc" and seeing what came up?  For instance: [linux-user/main.c](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/f368c33d5ab09dd5656924185cd975b11838cd25/linux-user/main.c#L3684).  Start there.  Though if you can't find main(), encrypting qemu in memory might be too ambitious.

Comment: @HostileFork even were the OP's contention that there is 'no documentation' is not correct as it happens, the way SO works is that people are here to answer stuff that's tough to google, like I did below.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is *"modify [vl.c](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/vl.c) and [qemu-options.hx](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/qemu-options.hx)"*. The latter is there as all the options processing is integrated into the help provision and so forth - i.e. the code is built dynamically. My normal approach is to pick a similar option and see how it's done.

The longer answer is that if you want the code upstreamed, you should probably discuss your proposal on the [qemu-devel mailing list](https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/qemu-devel).

The `#qemu` IRC channel on on [irc.oftc.net](http://www.oftc.net/) is also helpful. You will no doubt get some feedback. However, I'd suggest you might consider implementing this as a machine parameter rather than a command line option, unless you are going to make it work for all virtual machine types.

Comment: +1 for the spirit of wanting to help. But questions are assessed not on whether things are easy to Google or not. It's not easy to Google a lot of starting points for a lot of tasks; that's not the on-topic rule. And [qemu's getting started](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/GettingStartedDevelopers) says *"QEMU does not have a high level design description document - only the source code tells the full story."*  (Which is a way of saying "use the source, Luke"). A real answer needs to explain linux-user/main.c - generated, complementary? It'd get long. You've repeated the FAQ, mostly.

Comment: I've added options to qemu, and had them taken upstream. Really, you do want to modify `vl.c` and `qemu-options.hx` to do what he's trying to do! I've never touched `linux-user/main.c`. Just to prove it, here's a random patch I found that does just that: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-01/msg02839.html